# Is this code is prone to sql injection attacks?

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
sql= "SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE pubName = '" & myPubName & "'"
```

myPubName is already encapsulated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please read the guidelines to post a question and provide more details for better answers.

Comment: YES, SI, VI, TAK, JA

Comment: put hi 'or 1=1 -- in the place of myPubName and see the result. You will get your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "already encapsulated"?

Comment: post your servers id and access code and one of us will let you know ;)

Comment: Yes and your query will also gag on a title like `A Hobbit's Tale`

Comment: @Plutonix not using parameters would do exactly just that!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you are taking "myPubName" variable as user input and not checking it properly.

To inject SQL someone needs to write like this as the value of  "myPubName" variable  "'sometext' or 1=1"

Then the query will look like

SELECT * FROM BOOK WHERE pubName = 'sometext' or 1=1

Which will basically return all the rows from book table.